# Promisify mkdir on a recursive directory

Tags: node.js

I've promisified fs.mkdir().  When I try to create a single directory in /tmp, it works, but tI receive a ENOENT error when I try to create a nested directory, even though I sent in the `{ recursive: true }` option.

```
const mkdirAsync = util.promisify(fs.mkdir);
...

const ensureDir = ({ logger, createError }, event) => mkdirAsync(`/tmp/${event.mediaAssetUuid}/variants`, { recursive: true }).catch((err) => {
  if (err.code !== 'EEXIST') {
    const err2 = createError(
      err,
      { logger },
      `Internal Server Error.  Error generating image variant for file: ${event.mediaAssetUuid}`,
      null,
    );
    throw err2;
  }
});
```

Error:

```
 {
        "jse_shortmsg": "Internal Server Error.  Error generating image variant for file: 83ec01d8-8978-4eb0-9b0b-304f1e65cb14",
        "jse_cause": {
            "errno": -2,
            "code": "ENOENT",
            "syscall": "mkdir",
            "path": "/tmp/83ec01d8-8978-4eb0-9b0b-304f1e65cb14/variants"
        },
```

Comment: Which node version are you on? `recursive` was added fairly recently IIRC.

Comment: `recursive` option was added in node v10.12 AFAIK

Comment: @tkausl, v8.10.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Node version 10 is required to use the recursive option.